# CSWP not working in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server, cswp

I`m trying to use CSWP in SharePoint 2013 to showcase data from specific Content type: PMDASH

However its not pulling any values

Screenshot no. 1:

[image: screenshot1]

Screenshot no. 2:

[image: screenshot2]

Troubleshooting:

- Ran Full Crawl against the the specific site
- Changed Keyboard filter from "Only return items" to "Query from the search box"

Answer (score 3):

This is [known bug of Query Builder](http://www.markrackley.net/2014/02/14/sharepoint-2013-search-by-content-type-using-query-builder) itself. Change ContentType to shorter  ContentTypeId in your query (the value did not match the expected type) or use Content type names instead of identificators like:

```
{searchTerms} ContentType:Item
```